# Appium server not detecting the device connected through wifi

Tags: adb, appium, appium-android, python-appium

did `adb tcpip 5555` and `adb connect ipaddress` . The `adb devices` show the device. But when i run the appium server, its showing no android device connected.

The appium python code is

```
desired_caps = {}
desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Android'
desired_caps['automationName'] = 'uiautomator2'
desired_caps['udid'] = 'xx.xx.xx.xx:5555'
desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0.1'
desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'PackageName'
desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'activityName'

driver = webdriver.Remote('http://localhost:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)
```

The appium server error is

```
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 0 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
[debug] [ADB] Restarting adb
[debug] [ADB] Killing adb server on port 5037
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 0 device(s) connected
```

Answer (score 1):

found the reason why appium kept on killing the adb server and restarted it. found the solution  [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/why-appium-server-restart-adb-server-often/15479/3). 
    If adb server restart without root privilege, then appium Server can't connect to real device anymore.
Using `sudo` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. the solution was,

1. set up adb path in system variable(`~/sdk/platform-tools`). as the ADB path from where I was connecting the device over wifi(adb connect `xx.xx.xx.xx:5555`) was different from the adb under `~/sdk/platform-tools`.
2. use capability `<i>capabilities.setCapability("suppressKillServer", true);</i>` in code