# adb not detecting device when appium server is run

Tags: android, tcp, adb, appium, appium-android

I have connected my device with tcp. And its shows the device on adb devices.

```
adb connect 192.168.0.112
connected to 192.168.0.112:5555

adb devices
List of devices attached 
192.168.0.112:5555  device
```

But when appium server is run its unable to detect the device.

```
[ADB] Using adb from /home/sher/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[AndroidDriver] Retrieving device list
[debug] [ADB] Trying to find a connected android device
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 0 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Could not find devices, restarting adb server...
[debug] [ADB] Restarting adb
[debug] [ADB] Killing adb server on port 5037
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
```

Please soembody help. I have been stuck with this for few days. I tried many articles and nothing helped.

Comment: please stop posting identical questions https://stackoverflow.com/q/51438617/1778421

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51435239/1778421

Comment: no one is asnwering the question

Comment: @AlexP. jsut deleted the other question

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the original device id with 'ip address:port' combination and then run your test scripts. 
In your case (Assuming it's written in Java):

```
capabilities.setCapability("deviceId", "192.168.0.112:5555");
```

If this is not helping, please share more details such as device capabilities and test script.